# malloc and strcpy, illegall access, C

Tags: c, memory

I have read a lot about this but I can't find the error.

I have a procedure to say if a string value is found in another longer CSV string (in code below *inIP* is an IPv4 adress and *allow_hosts* is supposed to be a CSV list of IPv4 adresses, but it should work with any string and CSV list of strings).

code is the following:

```
bool stringFound(char* inIP,char* allow_hosts){
bool found=false;
int i =0;
int j =0;
char* ip;
printf("strlen(allow_hosts)=%d\n",strlen(allow_hosts));
while(i<strlen(allow_hosts) && !found){
    j=i;
    while(allow_hosts[i]!=',' && i<strlen(allow_hosts)){
        i++;
    }
    printf("jota = %d\n",j);
    printf("i = %d\n",i);
    printf("i-j+1 = %d\n",i-j+1);
    ip = malloc(i-j+1);//1 more for '\0'
    strncpy(ip,allow_hosts+j,i);//line 25, illegal access, problem one
    printf("it copies=%s\n",ip);
    ip[i-j]='\0';
    found = strcmp(ip,inIP)==0;
    //free(ip);//Problem two
    if(found)
        return found;
    i++;
}
return found;

};
```

When I test it once, there is no problem and result is correct, however, when I run it multiple times on a row, third or fourth gives me that error:

```
 malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion 
 `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2]))
   - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) 
 || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof
 (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) 
 & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && 
 ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
 Aborted (core dumped)
```

As far as I have read, it a problem with malloc, but the ammount of memory I'm allocating is enougth, when I call it with

```
 stringFound("8.8.7.8","127.0.0.1,8.8.8.8");
 stringFound("8.8.54.8","127.0.0.1,8.8.8.8,192.168.92.3");
```

It is printing

```
 jota = 10
 i = 17
 i-j+1 = 8
 it copies=8.8.8.8

 strlen(allow_hosts)=30
 jota = 0
 i = 9
 i-j+1 = 10
 //the error I showed above appears here
```

I also tested it with Valgrind, just called it as *valgrind ./myProgram* and it says:

```
 ==3406== Invalid write of size 1
 ==3406==    at 0x402D763: strncpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
 ==3406==    by 0x80485EB: stringFound (esta.c:25)
 ==3406==    by 0x80486CC: test (esta.c:49)
 ==3406==    by 0x8048803: main (esta.c:75)
 ==3406==  Address 0x41fe0f0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
```

'test' is the function which calls multiple times my procedure, and line 25 is marked as "problem here" in code.

As you can see I have a comment in free() line. If I use this line the error changes to

```
 Error in `./esta': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x09d11008 
 Aborted (core dumped)
```

I think both error are caused by the same, but I don't find the error

Answer (score 0):

```
strncpy(ip,allow_hosts+j,i);//line 25, illegal access, problem one
```

Yes, this should cause the problem. I think the third argument should be `i-j`, not `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You should write:

```
strncpy(ip,allow_hosts+j,i-j);
```

On any next iteration of the loop, `i` gets larger but you allocate room for only the ip string starting at j, so you must also only copy that part.

Answer (score 0):

```
strncpy(ip,allow_hosts+j,i);
```

Problem here is that you need a length of the fragment as a third argument, but you pass the ending position. You should pass `i-j`.

Answer (score 0):

2 problems:

```
ip = malloc(i-j+1);

// Wrong limit on strncpy
// strncpy(ip,allow_hosts+j,i);
strncpy(ip,allow_hosts+j,i-j);

// ip may not be null character terminated,  re-arrange code
ip[i-j]='\0';
printf("it copies=%s\n",ip);
// ip[i-j]='\0';
```

The `free()` problem is likely due to corruption of the above problem.

---

More subtle issues: the length return by `strlen` is type `size_t`.  This issue may not manifest itself readily should `size_t` and `int` be of similar size. - better not to count on that and use `size_t`.

```
size_t i =0;
size_t j =0;
// Change format specifier too.
printf("strlen(allow_hosts)=%zu\n",strlen(allow_hosts));

printf("jota = %zu",j);  // Review all printf formats
```

Answer (score 0):

- strstr() is a usable library function
- you dont need to malloc; just check the string
- if found, the string can be **part** of a larger valid dotted-quad string
- (note: strncpy() is a *terrible* function, and seldomly needed)

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int stringFound(char *inIP, char *allow_hosts){
char *cp;

cp = strstr(allow_hosts, inIP);

        /* IF substring is found:
        ** check if it is PART of a LARGER dotted quad string
        */
if (!cp) return 0;
if (cp > allow_hosts && cp[-1] >= '0' && cp[-1] <= '9' ) return 0;
cp += strlen(inIP); if (*cp >= '0' && *cp <= '9' ) return 0;

return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int found;
char *the_ip = "1.2.3.4";
char *should_fail = "5.2.3.4 ,1.2.3.45, 11.2.3.4, 1.2.3.4.";
char *should_match = "5.2.3.4 ,6.2.3.4,  1.2.3.4, 9.2.3.4";

found = stringFound(the_ip, should_fail);
printf("(should fail) Found=%d\n" , found);

found = stringFound(the_ip, should_match);
printf("(should match) Found=%d\n" , found);

return 0;
}
```